I need to type "zsh" every time i open git bash
Is there anyway to have zsh start automatically when using git bash?
I installed zsh on top of git bash and it is working as expected besides me having to type "zsh" every time i reopen it. Is there a way around this so it automatically starts zsh or do i have to type it every time.

what sort of computer is this on ?

@Fattie Im running windows 11 Pro

Step 6 here, maybe: https://dominikrys.com/posts/zsh-in-git-bash-on-windows/

While the suggestion of @Gairfowl likely works, I don't like it, because once you have it, you can't easily open an interactive bash shell  again (say, for testing something in bash). I have never used git-bash, but how exactly are you starting git-bash?

Maybe all you need is to echo $'\n'"exec zsh">>~/.bash_profile and log out. Just make sure you know where it is first, so that if something goes wrong you can fix it. If you can find it, you can also just use notepad to edit the line in. (Be wary of fancier editors that add extraneous formatting characters.)
